# Texturing by mask

Tags: three.js, glsl

I have tiles for landscape quadtree.
Each tile I texturizing by mask

```
vec4 frag = vec4 (0.0);
for (int i = 0; i <texture_length; i ++)
frag + = texture2D (texture [i], vUv * 6.0) * texture2D (mask [i], vUv);
```

where texture - an array of textures of grass, asphalt, black soil, etc. size of 256x256 px and "repeat = 6"
mask - array of masks. Size 512x512 px.

If I use one texture and one mask, I have 60 fps, but if the texture by mask at least 4 textures, it drops to 40 fps. In addition, when you add dynamically a tile felt millisecond freeze

Is it justified for 40 fps for this task, or you can achieve better performance?

Comment: Precompute textures if possible.

Comment: @Thomas, so, if I generate by masks textures (256x256px) with enough repeat, then I get the texture of approximately 2560x2560 px, I think it would require significantly more memory and will give more fps. I'll try it